# The right-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type

Tags: angular, typescript, amcharts

I have this code in JS and I need to make it work in TypeScript.

```
categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.adapter.add("dy", function(dy, target) {
      if (target.dataItem && target.dataItem.index & 2 == 2) {
        return dy + 25;
      }
      return dy;
    });
```

On This `2 == 2` i am getting error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is indeed the exact javascript you had :

```
target.dataItem && target.dataItem.index & 2 == 2
```

Then it is the same as

```
target.dataItem && target.dataItem.index & (2 == 2)
target.dataItem && target.dataItem.index & true
```

true will be coerced automatically by javascript as `1`, but TypeScirpt will not do that implicitly.

so if you write this :

```
target.dataItem && target.dataItem.index & 1
```

or

```
target.dataItem && target.dataItem.index & +true
```

in TypeScript, it compiles and does the same as your above javascript.

Otherwise your javascript was wrong already, and one of the other answers here already suggest xyou various corrections.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like typescript firstly does `2 == 2` which evals to `true`, and then `target.dataItem.index & true` which is wrong. Try to add parentheses `(target.dataItem.index & 2) == 2`.

Comment: @Pac0 Right, maybe just `target.dataItem.index & 1` ?

Comment: maybe, we can't really know for sure, until OP confirms

Comment: (target.dataItem.index & 1) == 1 I tried this and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably `target.dataItem.index & 2`, I'm guessing you meant double ampersands: `target.dataItem.index && 2`